# heatmap on bpmn diagram: ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'data' of object '[object ImageData]'

Tags: angular, typescript, heatmap, bpmn, camunda

I need help with adding heatmap on my bpmn diagram. I get strange error when HeatmapInstance tries to set data. I tried also

```
let currentData = heatmap.getData();
currentData.max = 20;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    currentData.data[i] = data[i];
}
```

and did not work (I did not get an error, but I didn't see anything as a heatmap).

```
const stats = {
                   'Task_198ld8o': 10,
                        'Task_0rny0oc': 20,
                        'Task_0kkopxk': 10
                    }
                    var heatmap = h337.create({
                        container: document.getElementById('canvas')
                    });

                    var data = [];
                    var registry = ViewerComponent.bpmnViewer.get('elementRegistry');

                    for (var i in registry.getAll()) {
                        var element = registry.getAll()[i];
                        if (stats[element.id] != null) {
                            const centerx = element.x + (element.width / 2);
                            const centery = element.y + (element.height / 2);
                            data.push({
                                x: centerx,
                                y: centery,
                                value: stats[element.id]
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    heatmap.setData({
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        data: data
                    });
```

Comment: Deleting img.data = imgData; row in a heatmap.js solved the problem for now. Waiting for other solutions.